# How to create a uniqule field in database mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I'm db beginner and i'm trying to write scrit which creates database, i want a field of chars to be unique is there any keyword in MYSQL which will guarantee that my field will be unique ?

Comment: `int auto_increment primary key` for integers, `unique index` for text.

Comment: -1 for lack of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
last_name varchar(255),
address varchar(255),
city varchar(255),
email varchar(255) UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

`email` is a field of characters, that HAS to be unique.

Comment: So it will not be possible to add two same emails ? Thats what i was looking for

Comment: exactly. If I register with your service with `foo@bar.com`, no one else will be able to register with that email. Note, you will still need to check when inserting to make sure something ACTUALLy inserted (just check the error coming from your SQL API.

Comment: @whd:- Just for your knowledge if you are specifying any column as UNIQUE then it means that there will be no duplicate values in that column.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [UNIQUE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) constraint in mYSQL

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t4 (
    col1 INT NOT NULL,
    col2 varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    col3 INT NOT NULL,
    col4 INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (col1, col3),
    UNIQUE KEY (col2, col4)
);
```

or like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(255) UNIQUE
)
```

Comment: -1 9 words is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more clear when you say "unique". Do you want each entry to contain a unique set of characters generated by SQL? If so, you can insert the following into your row:

```
 MD5(RAND())
```

Do you want to make sure that each row contains a unique entry? In which case you need to use the UNIQUE constraint on the column when creating the table. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Do you want each entry to contain a string with unique characters? ie: each character only appears once? In which case, I don't know if that's possible using just SQL.